# How to override checkbox styles if these inputs have a unique id

Tags: theme-development, woocommerce-offtopic, css

I'm trying to override default input checkbox styles, but not good result.

First of all these checkboxes and labels have unique ID. But if I try edit these checkboxes, no effect, because every checkbox and label has unique ID. I use this plugin *[Woocommerce Custom Fields](https://codecanyon.net/item/woocommerce-custom-fields/11332742)*.

Can someone push me to the right direction how I can styling these checkboxes? Thank you.

Example:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="sauce" checked="checked" name="wccf[product_field][82][]" id="wccf_product_field_toppings_sauce" class="wccf wccf_product_field wccf_checkbox wccf_product_field_checkbox" data-wccf-field-id="82">

<label for="wccf_product_field_toppings_sauce">Sauce</label>
```

Update: [jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/zbtprjsg/1/)

Comment: Why does it matter that they have a unique ID? Also generic HTML and CSS questions are off topic here, and best asked on https://stackoverflow.com.

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this?

```
.form-group:first-child {
  color: red;
}

.form-group:first-child > label {
  font-size: 12em;
}
```

I've changed your example from Codepen.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but I removed codepen link, because it misleading people. It's just styling example what I found in codepen.

Comment: Any way If I right understanding your probleme you should use pseudo selectors for apply some propertis to elements cause you can't get them by IDs

Comment: Try this ```input[value="sauce"] + label {
  color: red;
}``` It from your jsfiddle

Comment: I believe the Woocommerce Custom Fields has some hooks in particular for your form. Add specific classes to checkboxes and his labels and style them.